# Heroku + SSL Endpoint + SSL Cert from goDaddy. Is it secured

Tags: security, ssl, heroku, https

This is a very general question, not sure if its a duplicate as I have not really found my answer yet.

My company is very concerned about security of data, means, we are very particular about hosting our app and also our database. We are dealing with quite sensitive information such as medical data. We previously used AWS, means using a raw instance with no SSL at all. We migrated our web app to Heroku, as its purchased by cloudforce and we do not really need to take care about security, pen-testing all these stuff.

Then, we used heroku's SSL endpoints with a goDaddy SSL Cert which we think it might further enhance the security of the site.

I can say I am super noob in web security but are these measures enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with medical data, the measures you describe are not enough by themselves.
An SSL certificate will ensure your data is protected (encrypted) when it goes over the wire. A certificate will also identify the server to your users (mitigating man-in-the-middle attacks).

But when dealing with sensitive data, you'd also have to make sure your data is protected at rest (encrypted in the database or encrypting the database files themselves). You also have to take measures to prevent unauthorized access. This means that your users need to authenticate themselves and you have to give them access or prevent them from having access based on who they are or what role they are in ([RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)).

Google for any of the terms in this answer will give you lots more information.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is a general question, so only a general answer can be provided. Furthermore, it all depends on how you define "***enough***".

Of course using SSL give you the advantages of it, you are better of with it than without.

But make sure that you understand what SSL does and does not do. A limited list:

- SSL **does** encrypt the communication between client en server.
- SSL **does** conform the identity of the server (if he manage to keep his private key secure).
- SSL **does not** prevent any acces to your endpoint
- SSL **does not** conform in any way the identity of a user.